# On the average, how many times must a die be thrown until on gets a 6 -- where am I doing wrong

Tags: probability, bayesian, expected-value

I've already known one of the right solutions which is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n \cdot p \cdot q ^{n−1}$$
However I don't know why this logic doesn't work:
We are calculating the quantity -- $$E(N|Last=6)$$ where N is the number of rolls and Last=6 means only the last roll results in 6. So we have $$E(N|Last=6) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n \cdot P(n|Last=6)$$
where according to Bayes rule $$P(n|Last=6) = P(Last=6|n) \cdot P(n)/P(Last=6)$$
where $P(n)$ is uniform and $P(Last=6) = 1/6$ and $P(Last=6|n) = p \cdot q^{n-1}$ $$$$
If you plug these back in $E(N|Last=6) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n \cdot P(n|Last=6)$, the result is actually different. $$$$
Where am I doing wrong here and what's the right way of applying Bayes rule here?

Comment: @bof, you're right, just edited

Comment: I don't see what you need $\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(n)=1$ for. Where do you use it?

Comment: @Student7, yeah maybe I should say P(n) is uniform, edited

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Think of X- number of times until getting a 6.

You need to get different numbers from 6 in the (x-1)-th tries and at the x-th try you get a 6

X has geometric distribution, $p=1/6$ (probability of success) and $q=5/6$.

Now just compute $E(X)$

Comment: Yeah this way I can understand, my was trying to solve this with Bayes' rule and failed to do so. So my question is more like what I did wrong.

Comment: @YichengWang $P(n|Last=6) = p \cdot q^{n-1}$, and not what you have written

Comment: The think this is the other way around? Like given we roll a dice for N times, the probability that the last one is 6 is p⋅q^(n−1) ?

Comment: @YichengWang yes. ;)